# Why is java_executable_exec_path giving me a legacy "external" runfiles path

Tags: java, scala, bazel

Suppose I've got a minimal Scala `WORKSPACE` file like this:

```
workspace(name = "scala_example")

git_repository(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_scala",
    commit = "e9e65ada59823c263352d10c30411f4739d5df25",
    remote = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_repositories")
scala_repositories()

load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:toolchains.bzl", "scala_register_toolchains")
scala_register_toolchains()
```

And then a `BUILD`:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl", "scala_binary")

scala_binary(
    name = "example-bin",
    srcs = glob(["*.scala"]),
    main_class = "Example",
)
```

And an `Example.scala`:

```
object Example { def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("running") }
```

I can run `bazel run example-bin` and everything works just fine. My problem is that [this recent rules_scala PR](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/pull/409) changed the way the Java binary path is set to use the following:

```
ctx.attr._java_runtime[java_common.JavaRuntimeInfo].java_executable_exec_path
```

…instead of the previous `ctx.executable._java.short_path`.

After this change the Java binary path includes an `external` directory in the path, which seems to be a legacy thing (?). This means that after this change, if I run the following:

```
bazel run --nolegacy_external_runfiles example-bin
```

It no longer works:

```
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/example-bin
.../.cache/bazel/_bazel_travis/03e97e9dbbfe483081a6eca2764532e8/execroot/scala_example/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/example-bin.runfiles/scala_example/example-bin_wrapper.sh: line 4: .../.cache/bazel/_bazel_travis/03e97e9dbbfe483081a6eca2764532e8/execroot/scala_example/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/example-bin.runfiles/scala_example/external/local_jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory
ERROR: Non-zero return code '127' from command: Process exited with status 127
```

It also breaks some scripts I have that expect non-`external` paths.

Why is `java_executable_exec_path` giving me this `external` path? Is there some option I can give bazel to convince it not to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the slow reply -- it appears that this is because the Scala rules erroneously used `java_executable_exec_path` whereas they should have used `java_executable_runfiles_path`.

I sent a pull request to fix it, then I realized that you already did in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/commit/4235ef58782ce2ec82981ea70b808397b64fe7df

Since the latter is now available at HEAD with Bazel, I'll remove the ugly if at least.